# What does sys.stdin.read() return exactly in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, standard-library

I am new to python and am working on interactive shell. I was trying out python standard library and I read from the documentation that `stdin.read()` returns a string argument.
But when I go ahead and print the variable storing input value it displays a random character. Confused on what it signifies

```
>>>input=sys.stdin.read()
>>>1 2
>>>sys.stdout.write(input)
>>>1 2 
   4
```

What does the 4 signifies. Why is it displayed. If instead I do `print(input)`. It works fine and returns `"1 2"`.Is it just a garbage value or does it have some significance.

Further when I split Input to get a list. It returns only two elements `['1', '2']`. As expected. I am curious why 4 is displayed and it is not constant.

```
>>>input=sys.stdin.read()
>>>1 2 3 4
>>>sys.stdout.write(input)
>>>1 2 3 4
   8
```

Print and Split again works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The `4` or `8` is returned by `sys.stdout.write`. It "signifies" how many characters (or bytes) have been printed.

Like the [documentation on `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) states:

> These streams are regular text files like those returned by the open() function.

and these streams have a [`write`](https://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.write) method:

> Write the given bytes-like object, b, to the underlying raw stream, **and return the number of bytes written.**

You can simply ignore it or if it really troubles you just catch the return in a variable:

```
>>> bytes_written = sys.stdout.write(input)
1 2

>>> bytes_written
4
```